# Creating and Overwriting Google Sheets Table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to create/remove/re-create a table with information pulled from Google's AdminDirectory service and have the ability to overwrite that information with different groups of users using a custom menu I've already set up.

To be specific, I'd like for each menu's function to start with clearing any data from the sheet, then create a table with headers that displays each user's Full Name and Email Address for that group. The reason being I want to be able to swap between which groups are displayed.

What's the best way to do this? So far I just know how to pull the user information out of AdminDirectory and log it.

```
function displayUserFunction()
{
  var domain = 'domainname.com';
  var userDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain: domain, orderBy: 'givenName'});

  var users = userDirectory.users;
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
  {
    var user = users[i];
    Logger.log('Name is: %s. Email is: %s', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets then show what you tried to write the data to the spreadsheet instead of logging it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayUserFunction() {
  const domain = 'domainname.com';
  const userDirectory = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain: domain, orderBy: 'givenName'});
  const users = userDirectory.users;
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');//add your sheet name
  sh.clearContents();//clear sheet of all contents
  oA=[["Full Name","Email"]];//start with headers
  users.forEach(u =>{oA.push([u.name,u.primaryEmail])});//add data for each user
  sh.getRange(1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//load array into sheet
}
```